# Alamofire assertionFailure - needNewBodyStream did not find UploadRequest

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I'm trying to send a `POST` request using alamofire. but on a request i'm keeping get this error:

```
   assertionFailure("needNewBodyStream did not find UploadRequest.")


    Alamofire/SessionDelegate.swift, line 178
    2020-12-09 16:48:32.746737+0330 Dericoin[29553:862552] Fatal error: needNewBodyStream did not find UploadRequest.: file Alamofire/SessionDelegate.swift, line 178
```

my request :

```
let paramsDict: [String: Any]? = [...]
let headersDict: [String: Any]? = [...]    
AF.request("https://....", method: .post, parameters: paramsDict, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headersDict)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    //something
            }
```

i'm using `Alamofire v5.4` and also tested v5.2 and v5.3; `iOS 14` and `Swift 5`.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with network analytics frameworks ( i was using `Wormholy`). Those can interfere with `Alamofire`'s internal storage.

So removing the pod solved the problem. If someone had the same problem wanted to follow the issue; this is the link:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3373